# DC/OS installations hangs at 50% of Pre-Flight

Tags: apache-mesos

I want to test the community editon of DC/OS and I cannot get it to progress past 50% of pre-flight:
[image]

I followed the gui instructions outlined [here](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/custom/gui/) and started the installation in verbose mode. This is the last non "GET preflight" output:

```
Using async_delegate with callback
executing command ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-oConnectTimeout=10', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', '-oBatchMode=yes', '-oPasswordAuthentication=no', '-p22', '-i', '/genconf/ssh_key', '-tt', 'core@192.168.0.16', '\n#/bin/sh\n# setenforce is in this path\nPATH=$PATH:/sbin\n\ndist=$(cat /etc/*-release | sed -n \'s@^ID="\\(.*\\)"$@\\1@p\')\n\nif ([ x$dist != \'xrhel\' ] && [ x$dist != \'xcentos\' ]); then\n  echo "$dist is not supported. Only RHEL and CentOS are supported" >&2\n  exit 0\nfi\n\nversion=$(cat /etc/*-release | sed -n \'s@^VERSION_ID="\\(.*\\)"$@\\1@p\')\nif [ $version -lt 7 ]; then\n  echo "$version is not supported. Only >= 7 version is supported" >&2\n  exit 0\nfi\n\nsudo setenforce 0 && sudo sed -i \'s/^SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/g\' /etc/sysconfig/selinux\n\nsudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo <<-\'EOF\'\n[dockerrepo]\nname=Docker Repository\nbaseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg\nEOF\n\nsudo yum -y update\n\nsudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d\nsudo tee /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf <<- EOF\n[Service]\nExecStart=\nExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --storage-driver=overlay -H fd://\nEOF\n\nsudo yum install -y docker-engine\nsudo systemctl start docker\nsudo systemctl enable docker\n\nsudo yum install -y wget\nsudo yum install -y git\nsudo yum install -y unzip\nsudo yum install -y curl\nsudo yum install -y xz\nsudo yum install -y ipset\n\nsudo getent group nogroup || sudo groupadd nogroup\n']
GET preflight
GET preflight
GET preflight
GET preflight
GET preflight
GET preflight
```

I've also downloaded the logs from the gui which contain:

```
[
    {
        "chain_name": "preflight",
        "hosts": {
            "192.168.0.16:22": {
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "cmd": [
                            "/usr/bin/ssh",
                            "-oConnectTimeout=10",
                            "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no",
                            "-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                            "-oBatchMode=yes",
                            "-oPasswordAuthentication=no",
                            "-p22",
                            "-i",
                            "/genconf/ssh_key",
                            "-tt",
                            "core@192.168.0.16",
                            "echo",
                            "INSTALL",
                            "PREREQUISITES"
                        ],
                        "date": "2016-09-06 13:27:40.570649",
                        "pid": 20,
                        "returncode": 0,
                        "stderr": [
                            "",
                            "Connection to 192.168.0.16 closed.",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "stdout": [
                            "INSTALL PREREQUISITES\r",
                            ""
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "host_status": "running",
                "tags": {
                    "role": "master"
                }
            },
            "192.168.0.17:22": {
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "cmd": [
                            "/usr/bin/ssh",
                            "-oConnectTimeout=10",
                            "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no",
                            "-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                            "-oBatchMode=yes",
                            "-oPasswordAuthentication=no",
                            "-p22",
                            "-i",
                            "/genconf/ssh_key",
                            "-tt",
                            "core@192.168.0.17",
                            "echo",
                            "INSTALL",
                            "PREREQUISITES"
                        ],
                        "date": "2016-09-06 13:27:40.553732",
                        "pid": 21,
                        "returncode": 0,
                        "stderr": [
                            "",
                            "Connection to 192.168.0.17 closed.",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "stdout": [
                            "INSTALL PREREQUISITES\r",
                            ""
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "host_status": "running",
                "tags": {
                    "role": "agent"
                }
            },
            "192.168.0.18:22": {
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "cmd": [
                            "/usr/bin/ssh",
                            "-oConnectTimeout=10",
                            "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no",
                            "-oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
                            "-oBatchMode=yes",
                            "-oPasswordAuthentication=no",
                            "-p22",
                            "-i",
                            "/genconf/ssh_key",
                            "-tt",
                            "core@192.168.0.18",
                            "echo",
                            "INSTALL",
                            "PREREQUISITES"
                        ],
                        "date": "2016-09-06 13:27:40.521035",
                        "pid": 22,
                        "returncode": 0,
                        "stderr": [
                            "",
                            "Connection to 192.168.0.18 closed.",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "stdout": [
                            "INSTALL PREREQUISITES\r",
                            ""
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "host_status": "running",
                "tags": {
                    "role": "agent"
                }
            }
        },
        "total_agents": 2,
        "total_hosts": 3,
        "total_masters": 1
    }
]
```

The bootstrap machine is my computer and the master/agents are CentOS 7 KVM machines running on my computer. I have also made sure that the SSH keys works with no passphrases. What do I need to do in order to make the setup progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to use the Advanced installer which does not depend on having the SSH keys on the bootstrap node which can cause such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The installer is hanging on `install prereqs` stage. This stage can take a long time depending on your network connectivity from the machines it's running to the larger internet as well as host performance.

This stage installs prerequisite packages (using yum on CentOS), installs and configures Docker, as well as ensuring the hosts are in a minimally install-able state for DC/OS.

How long did you run this for before exiting?

As an aside, when an install stage begins, the progress bar counts as 50% of that host, 100% is reached when the host completes installation. Since the installer runs parallel SSH sessions (30 is the default, but can be set in the config yaml with the `parallelism` parameter), it's doing both your hosts at once, and neither are complete, so it's showing 50% complete.

Comment: I am testing it using KVM machines (2CPUs and 4GB of ram each) on my pc. I let it run for over 30 mins. The strange thing is that during the process the machines sit idle and `/opt/mesosphere` and `/var/lib/zookeeper` do not exist on any of the nodes.